# Creating a textured Mesh for 3D printing

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

I need to create a textured object to be 3D printed. Is there a way I can import a texture and apply it to my mesh so that the mesh changes to become textured? thanks !

Comment: You can use a displace modifier https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/deform/displace.html

Comment: @Nora I can't understand if you wish a textured file that can be printed *textured* in 3D? If yes, knowing which printer or printing service you're going to use would help...